# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null, Element does exist

Tags: javascript

Before you downvote, I've read a lot of questions and it didn't help me.
My Javascript's `alert` returns null even when there is a value in the input type.

Here's the code :-

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById('p0002') != null) {
    var str = document.getElementById("p0002").value;
}
else {
    var str = null;
}
alert(str);
</script>

 <input type="hidden" name="p0002" id="p0002" value="1" >
 <input type="hidden" name="p0003" id="p0003" value="0" >
 <input type="hidden" name="p0004" id="p0004" value="2" >
```

It always returns `null`. The error in console says :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Trying to fix it since last 1 hour. What is wrong here?

Comment: Is the jQuery tag correct?

Comment: Did you tried to place your javascript bellow HTML (before closing body tag)?

Comment: Because the element doesn't exist at the point you execute your code (you literally output the input field AFTER the javascript code has run). Use an onload event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your `JavaScript` in `window.onload`. Currently your `JavaScript` is executing before the element exists:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('p0002') != null) {
        var str = document.getElementById("p0002").value;
    }
    else {
        var str = null;
    }
    alert(str);
}
</script>
```

Another thing you can do is move the script tag to be after the elements you're referencing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p0002" id="p0002" value="1" >
<input type="hidden" name="p0003" id="p0003" value="0" >
<input type="hidden" name="p0004" id="p0004" value="2" >
<script>
if (document.getElementById('p0002') != null) {
    var str = document.getElementById("p0002").value;
}
else {
    var str = null;
}
alert(str);
</script>
```

Comment: Can happen to anyone :) I will update the answer with the option to also move the script below the element definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Your script should be excuted after inputs  being added to DOM. The most crossbrowser way to make your script work, is to move it just before your `<body>` tag is closed, and wrap it into an immediate function:

```
<script>
(function() {
   if (document.getElementById('p0002') != null) {
       var str = document.getElementById("p0002").value;
   } else {
       var str = null;
   }
       alert(str);
 })();
</script>
</body>
```

This is faster to execute than an `onload` handler because this waits only for the DOM to be ready, not for all images to load. And, this works in every browser.

Answer (score -1):

Here your script should be after html.