# How to generate textbox in Asp.Net Mvc projecct

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, textbox

[image]

I get all products from database to my Asp.Net Mvc View. So far so good.
I just put textbox in every row with plus and minus buttons and then Ok button to update Quantity in database. 
But every Click goes to the first textbox. Here is my code

```
  <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                Products

            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>

                <td> 
             <input type='text' name='qty@(item.ComputerId)' id='qty@(item.ProductId)'/>

                <Button class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" name="add" onclick='javascript: document.getElementById(qty@(item.ProductId)).value++;' value='+' />
                <Button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-minus" name="subtract" onclick='javascript: subtractQty(qty@(item.ProductId));' value='-' />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update();">Ok</button>
            </td> 

            </tr>
        }

    </table>

And JavaScript is:


   function subtractQty(name) {
            if (document.getElementById(name).value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
               document.getElementById(name).value--;
        }
```

But now I get this  Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Where do you delcare your textboxes in you view?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Well you're right, your textboxes probably have the same `id`. So you can start by giving them different `id`s to uniquely identify each textbox.

```
    @{
        int counter  = 0;
        foreach (var item in Model)
            {

             <input type='text' name='counter' id='counter' />
                            <Button class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("counter").value++;' value='+' />
                            <Button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-minus" onclick='javascript: subtractQty(counter);' value='-' /> 

       counter ++;
        }
   }
```

Then you have to alter your `JavaScript` method `subtractQty` to know which textbox the increment or decrement should be applied to.

I might tweak your method a little to use the approach below:

```
function subtractQty(textboxId) {
            if (document.getElementById(textboxId).value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
                document.getElementById(textboxId).value--;
        }
```

Comment: @jamiedang thank you for your response but they are as many as those generated products from database, how should I know how many they will be and the name. Shoudn't be as Munzer response? Thank you again

Comment: that's why i changed the name and the id to  `counter` because at every iteration the counter would change making each texbox unique. The number of products wouldn't be a problem

Comment: thank you again, but stil remains the same problem. All goes to the first one.

Comment: Ah you are right and I'll make the correction soon, it's just the Id I'm using.

Comment: Right now I'am geting 500 (Internal Server Error) with wrone link.. like this....
http://localhost:25411/home/GetProducts?id=2&_=1497305386795
It should be http://localhost:25411/home/GetProducts?id=2
I don't know where from coming the rest &_=1497305386795

Comment: I have updated my code please check, now I get this  Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null .. I think the solution is closer now.. please help..

Comment: Check your `DOM` you'll find out the culprit. The thing is if you use your model properties to uniquely identify your text boxes you must make sure the property you are using doesn't returns `null` and also beware of how you concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

You should give unique names and ids for your text box, you can do this through your loop, like appending item id to the `qty` 
like this

```
 <input type='text' name='qty@Item.ID' id='qty@Item.ID' />
```

note that I assumed that your id field name is ID which is not correct, change it to the name of your field.

then in your javascript function, add one more param which will take the name which is `qty@Item.ID`, get the element by name using this param and update its value accordingly

```
<Button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-minus" name="subtract" onclick="javascript: subtractQty(@Item.ID);" value='-' />
```

your js function

```
function subtractQty(id) {
            if (document.getElementById("qty"+id.toString()).value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
                document.getElementById("qty"+id.toString()).value--;
        }
```

Comment: thank you for response. My Id field name is tem.ProductId and I changed it to name='qty@item.ProductId' but now there is no action when  click those + and - buttons. I get this error when I hit F12  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null". Thank you again!

Comment: are you passing the name parameter to your function  ?

Comment: check my edit, i added passing the param name maybe it was missing

Comment: I have updated my code please check, now I get this  Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null .. I think the solution is closer now.. please help..

Comment: Hello Jonas, check my update, maybe passing the param wasn't correct, try this way now and let me know please

Comment: the same Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null . You know my buttons are in my PartialView and javascript in my Index View, I don't if it doesn't matter.

Comment: please don't give up.. ;) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null  stil the same error... I realy need to solve this problem..

Comment: Hi, sorry i was busy, can you console.log(name) in subtractqty function and tell me the value you are getting ?

Comment: also check my edit, i hope this will be the last, and it will work

Comment: thank you for your patience.  It says Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference and console says function onclick(event)
{
javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;
} May I give you my email and then you send me your email and then to send you the hole project..please...;) I know you do not have time..;)

Comment: Hello Jonas, It is good practice to solve your issues by yourself, that's the only way you will learn, as i told you, can you add `console.log(id);` in your function ? and tell me what you see

Comment: it says 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: before the error, what your console  out the id ? 
I tested the code on my local, and it worked, just try and check what is wrong with your code, is it outputing the correct id ? check the rendered element ids ? is it correct ? you can inspect element for your button and see the id passed to the function, also make sure that inputs names are qty+productid. 
[this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) might help you with debuggin.

Comment: It's very strange that it's working for you. Even if I give a value direct to subtractQty() like  ` <Button name="subtract" onclick= "javascript: subtractQty(5);" value='-' /> `  and and my Javascript  ` function subtractQty(id) {
            console.log(id);
            alert(id);
            if (document.getElementById("qty" + id.toString()).value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
                document.getElementById("qty" + id.toString()).value--;
        }
`   this is not giving me something on console message but the same error when I hit F12. Please past yours

Comment: I have no idea, the strange thing is its not working on your machine It should work

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with the following code:

### View Code:

```
  @int tempno=0;
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>

            <td> 
             <input type='text' name='qty@(tempno)' id='qty@(tempno)' />
                <Button class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" name="add" onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;' value='+' />
                <Button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-minus" name="subtract" onclick='javascript: subtractQty();' value='-' /> |
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update();">Ok</button>


        </tr>
       @temp++
    }
```

jquery code:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var product = row.find('td:eq(0)').text();
var quantity= row.find('td:eq(1)').text();
```

Hope it will be helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: Thank you for response but gives me error about tempno says  "
the name tempno does not exist in the current context" ..even if I write it like this  @ {int tempno=0};

Comment: I have updated my code please check, now I get this  Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null .. I think the solution is closer now.. please help..

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null means that you're probably didn't set an id in order for the function to look for the value, so it can retrieve it.

Solution:

check like this:

if (document.getElementById('cal_preview') != null) {
    str = document.getElementById("cal_preview").value;
}

useful link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758730/3397630